# How to display nested data in FirestoreRecycler?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I've been reading about how to display data in a `RecyclerView` through `FirestoreRecycler`, and came across some questions in StackOverflow and this [post](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).

However, my case seems to be somewhat different, and I'm struggling with my custom class made to read the data from the `Firestore Database` and map it into my `Model` object, so that I could use the `Firestore Adapter` in my `RecyclerView`.

For instance, here is an image from my database: [Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjKXU.png)

And here is the code I managed to create:

### **Model Class**

**Getters/Setters removed for readability.**

```
public class Building {

    private Tenant tenant;
    private Room room;
    private String name;
    private String address;

}
```

Here is the custom class I created to try and get the data from the database, so I could display it in the RecyclerView:

```
public class BuildingDocument {

    public List<Building> building;
}
```

The code for creating the `FirestoreRecyclerOptions`:

```
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference osRef = db.collection("Building");
    private DocumentReference docRef = osRef.document("forsale");

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewOs);

        Query query = osRef.orderBy("building",
                Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<BuildingDocument> options =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<BuildingDocument>()
                        .setQuery(query, BuildingDocument.class)
                        .build();

        listAdapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

This method, however, gives an NullPointException error,

**`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference`**

And finally, my `FirestoreAdapter` class:

```
 public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<BuildingDocument, FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public FirestoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<BuildingDocument> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull BuildingDocument model) {

      holder.buildingNameItem.setText(model.building.get(position).getName());
        
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bd_item, parent, false);

        return new FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView buildingNameItem;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            buildingNameItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bdNameItem);
        }
    }
}
```

So, how could I fetch the data from my database and properly display it in the FirestoreAdapter?

**EDIT**

Results of the document: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69g3P.png)

Comment: Do you have any other methods inside the `BuildingDocument` class? Where is `building()` coming from?

Comment: No other methods inside `BuildingDocument`. Essentially, what I have is an Map<String,ArrayList> where I add my `Building` objects to the array in order to send the Map to the Firestore database.

The `BuildingDocument` class is based on your Medium post.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Then where does this `building()` come from?

Comment: Apologies, that must've slipped through my testing. I will edit it, as it should be `model.get(position).getName()`.

Comment: Most likely it should be `model.building.get(position).getName()`, isn't it?

Comment: Correct, however, the NPE mentioned in the post still remains the same. Perhaps there's another `@Override` to be made in the Adapter?

Comment: Please show us the entire adapter class, and not just the onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Done. If there is anything that seems wrong, just point out, as I'm doing some testing as we speak and I might of have left something out.

Comment: Have you tried to pass `osRef` rather than `query` to the `.setQuery()` method? Something like `.setQuery(osRef, BuildingDocument.class)`, does it work this way?

Comment: Does not work, `'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference` remains the same error.

Comment: Can please show us another document like to one you shared?

Comment: The one from the database?

Comment: Yes. Are you sure all the documents have the exact same field?

Comment: I will write another document for it. While we're at it, as you can see, I am trying only to read the name in the adapter, not all the fields. Is that possible? Or does it require for me to read/get all of the fields wether or not I want do display them?

Comment: You're getting the entire document not only particular fileds. Show us a screenshot with the result of the documents.

Comment: There, I edited the results in, if I understood what you meant correctly, of course. It's printed in the Logcat.